# Laravel Order By certain value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'd like for one of my relationships to return ordering by a certain value as follows:

```
return $this->hasMany('Photo', 'owner_id')->where('active', '=', '1')->where('visible', '=', '1')->orderByRaw("(`id` = ?) DESC", array($showphoto));
```

But the above code returns this :

```
select * from `photos` where `photos`.`owner_id` = '4' and `active` = '1' and `visible` = '1' order by (`id` = '') DESC
```

How do I get the $showphoto variable to be in the order by?

Answer (score 0):

It won't show you that it was injected since you are not currently triggering the query.
When you will chain the `get()` method to it, it will "inject" the `$showphoto` and execute the query.

I am not aware of a way you can see the full query including the values of the parameters before actually executing the query.